# How to write only the last 10 lines to a file in C?

Tags: c, linux, file

I am trying to implement a simple command history. This programme writes all commands to a text file, but I want it to store only the last 10 commands.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

void last_ten_commands(char *command)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("history.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", command);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    char  command[SIZE];

    fputs("Enter the command\n", stdout);
    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", command);
        if (strcmp(command,"exit") == 0)
            break;
        last_ten_commands(command);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Store them in a stack or a list.

Comment: OK. What's the problem?

Comment: Ex: i have 10 command. After i am enter the 11th command. In history file delete the first line then add the 11th command in last.

Comment: Why not store them in a stack and then write into a file the first 10 elements of the stack. Or a cyclic list?

Comment: @sakthi you cannot delete the first line in a file. You have to copy the whole file to a new file line by line skipping the first line. Otherwise do as Felipe Sulser suggests.

Comment: @Michael Walz..Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to keep the history list internally in the program, as a simple ten-element array, and flush the array to file when the history changes.

To know what index in the array to place the next element, use e.g.

```
current_index = (current_index + 1) % 10;
```

That will make sure that you don't go out of bounds of the array, and that it circulates when it reached the tenth element.

As for the history array, it could be a simple array of `char *`, or similar.